# remapping Vimperator's backspace key

Tags: firefox, remapping, vimperator

How can I remap the backspace key in Vimperator? I can't find its  equivalent, like  or  etc.

I'm sure I'm staring right at it.

Any hints you can give me would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent to Backspace in vim/vimperator is < BS >. So you can remap Backspace with the following .vimperatorrc entry:

```
[remapping of choice] <BS> [what you want to remap Backspace to]
```

Ex:

```
" remap Backspace to Shift-H (go back one page) in normal mode
nnoremap <BS> H
```

For more information, try :help map, :help key-mapping and :help key-notation